# stream_copy_to_stream() Error when uploading a 3MB PDF File

Tags: php, laravel, file, upload, config

I am trying out what file size I can upload in my laravel application.
With file size of 3MB I ran into this error:

```
stream_copy_to_stream(): Read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=21 Is a directory
```

I googled it and all solutions were to increase the constants in `php.ini` file. I had multiple of those and changed every single one of them to `1000M` - before they were all `100M` - which is weird as well because 3MB should work then.

I read lots of question about this but none had a solution for me.

Comment: There could also be a limitation by NGINX or Apache, did you restart php?

Comment: What are you using to serve your project?

Comment: @Aless55 what exactly do you mean by restarting php?

Comment: @Abdulrahman this is happening on my localhost. I use `php artisan serve` and run it on my Mac

Comment: You could run php via php-fpm then you will need to restart this service after changes to php.ini.

Comment: @Aless55 alright will try that, thanks for now :)